# How to reload div with context on jquery in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I got voting with jQuery, voting is working now, but after vote I want refresh div to get results. I found, that it should be done with load included template. But how to send context for refresh? And what View it should be?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".vote_button" ).click(function() {
            $.post($(this).parent().attr("name"), $(this).parent().serialize(),
            function(data){
                alert("Data sended: " + data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Parent template:

```
{% for action in action_list %}

    <div id="vote">
        {% include "feed/action_photo.html" %}
    </div>
```

action_photo.html:

```
{% if action.voted%}
    <p>{{ action.target.vote_count }} {{ action.target.rating }}</p>
{% else %}
    <form id="photo_vote_form" name ="{% url "vote" action.target.id %}">{%csrf_token%}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="button" class = "vote_button" value="Send" />
    </form> 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something in your success method like this:

```
function(data){
    $('#vote p').empty().html(data);
});
```

Comment: Does not work properly, fills all divs on page with success report.

Comment: @Hrkonnen How many divs do you have with id of `#vote`, if one then you have a valid markup otherwise invalid markup and that will behave differently.

Comment: I make divs in loop {% for action in action_list %}. Is it possible to set them unique id and use it in js?

Comment: @Harkonnen yes you can add a incremental number like `#vote1, #vote2 ... n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".vote_button" ).click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.post($(this).parent().attr("name"), $(this).parent().serialize(),
            function(data){
                $(this).parent().parent().html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code under success function will get the parent of clicked voting button then gets its parent which is the div you have given id as "vote" after that it changes this div's html with your "data" content, also please don't repeat same id for different divs(elements) instead use class in this case. Let me know if my answer is helpful.